# Extracting values from a reversed linked list

Tags: swift, string, linked-list, singly-linked-list

#### Question:

> You have two numbers represented by a linked list, where each node contains a single digit. The digits are stored in reverse order, such that the 1 's digit is at the head of the list. Write a function that adds the two numbers and returns the sum as a linked list.

#### An Example:

> Input: (7-> 1 -> 6) + (5 -> 9 -> 2).
>
> That is: 617 + 295.
>
> Output: 2 -> 1 -> 9.
>
> That is: 912.

In order to begin with this question, I first created a class that would define what a linked list:

#### Step 1: Defining the linked list

```
class Node: CustomStringConvertible{
    var value: Int
    var next: Node?
    var description: String{
        if next != nil {
          return "\(value) -> \(next!)"
        }
        else{
            return "\(value) -> \(next)"
        }
    }
    init(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

#### Step: 2 - Generated the linked list, from user input of integer values

```
func generateList (num: Int) -> Node {
    var stringNum = Array(String(num).characters)
    let head = Node.init(value:Int(String(stringNum.first!))!)
    var current = head

    for i in 1..<stringNum.count{
        let num = Int(String(stringNum[i]))
        current.next = Node.init(value: num!)
        current = current.next!
    }
    return head
}

let list = generateList(num: 716)

// The following prints out: 7 -> 1 -> 6 -> nil
```

Then I proceeded over to reverse the linked list using following function.

#### Step 3: Reverse the linked list

```
func reverseLinkedList (head: Node?) -> Node?{

    var current = head
    var prev: Node?
    var next: Node?

    while current != nil {
        next = current?.next
        current?.next = prev
        prev = current
        current = next
    }
    return prev
}

let reversedList = reverseLinkedList(head: list)

// The following prints out is: 6 -> 1 -> 7 -> nil
```

#### Step 4: The idea behind this step is to extract the values on each of the nodes, cast them as a string and then concatenate them to a string variable and then lastly cast the string value into an Int and then use that Int value and eventually add them.

```
func getValuesFrom (head: Node?) -> Int {

    var string = ""
    var current = head

    while current != nil {
        var stringVal = String(describing: current?.value)
        string += stringVal
        current = current?.next
    }

    return Int(string)!
}
```

Here is where I am having a problem:

When I plug in the following into this function like so:

```
getValuesFrom(head: reversedList)
```

I get the following error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

And I can't seem to figure out why I having a problem and would really appreciate any sort of insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to convert back and forth between String and the linked list, except to print it for results. This is done simply like this:

```
class Node {
  var value: Int
  var next: Node?

  // init and generator can be the same method
  init(value: Int) {
    // store ones place and divide by 10
    self.value = value % 10
    var nextValue = value / 10

    // set up for loop
    var currentNode = self

    while nextValue > 0 {
      // create a new Node
      // store ones place and divide by 10
      let next = Node(value: nextValue % 10)
      nextValue /= 10

      // make the new Node the next Node
      currentNode.next = next

      // set up for next iteration
      currentNode = next
    }
  }
}

// make the list printable
extension Node: CustomStringConvertible {
  var description: String{
    if let next = next {
      return "\(value) -> \(next)"
    }
    else {
      return "\(value) -> nil"
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
print(Node(value: 671)) // prints "7 -> 1 -> 6 -> nil"
```

There is also no need to reverse the lists, given your question.

To sum the lists you can do just as you've said, convert to an `Int`, add them, then generate a new list:

```
extension Node {
  func toValue() -> Int {
    var place = 10
    var current = self
    // add each value and multiply by the place value
    // first is 1, second 10, third 100, etc.
    var result = current.value
    while let next = current.next {
      result += next.value * place
      place *= 10
      current = next
    }
    return result
  }
}
```

Then all you need is to overload the addition operator...

```
func +(lhs: Node, rhs: Node) -> Node {
  return Node(value: lhs.toValue() + rhs.toValue())
}
```

and test...

```
let first = Node(value: 617)
let second = Node(value: 295)
print(first)
print(second)
print(first + second)
```

Result:

> 7 -> 1 -> 6 -> nil
>
> 5 -> 9 -> 2 -> nil
>
> 2 -> 1 -> 9 -> nil

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it!

Comment: If there's an answer to your question it's best to accept it. That way others who are looking for similar questions will find this one with an accepted answer.

Comment: I will definitely keep that in mind and do so going forward, thank you for all your help!!!